# Upload file and 404.13 error

Tags: asp.net

I have created a web page by ASP.NET 4.5. The `maxRequestLength` property of web.config was set. I tried to upload a file more than 29Mb but it was impossible. I changed the maximum allowed content length of `Request Filtering` from IIS management. Moreover, I checked the `applicationHost.config` and there wasn't `requestLimit` tag there. However, I added and then removed the tag to check the result. My OS is windows 8.

I couldn't upload any file more than 29Mb. Every time I tried, I got the `HTTP Error 404.13` message. I wonder if anybody can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/http-error-40413-not-found-request.html

Comment: I set `maxRequestLength` in **kB** and `maxAllowedContentLength` in **Bytes**. The problem had been solved.